# How do I add the GUI controls to my Mayavi mesh?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I've created a mesh gird and looped through the dataset to update the values of the mesh. The problem is that I need to add buttons specifically pause and play to the Mayavi view which would allow me to control the view like an animation.

```
import xarray as xr
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np
import time as t

# Read the NetCDF file using xarray
#dataset = xr.open_dataset('time_series.nc', decode_times=False)
dataset = xr.open_dataset('time_series.nc', decode_times=False)

#Extract latitude, longitude, and temperature data
latitude = dataset['LAT852_1008'].values
longitude = dataset['LON2982_3207'].values


temperature = dataset['WATER_TEMP'][0,0,:,:] 
print(len(temperature[0]))
# Create a meshgrid of latitude and longitude
lon_grid, lat_grid = np.meshgrid(longitude, latitude)

# Plot the temperature data on a globe using Mayavi

mlab.figure(size=(800, 600), bgcolor=(0, 0, 0))

for time in range(len(dataset['WATER_TEMP']['TIME'])):
    temperatureNEW=dataset['WATER_TEMP'][time,0,:,:] 
    mesh=mlab.mesh(lon_grid, lat_grid, temperatureNEW, colormap='jet', scalars=temperature)
    mlab.colorbar(title='Temperature')
    t.sleep(10)
    mlab.savefig('frame_%04d.png' % time)
mlab.show()
```

I've tried adding PYQT gui to my plain code but it shows me "argument 1 has unexpected type 'MayaviScene'"

```
import xarray as xr
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np
import time as t

# Import PyQt modules
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPalette
from mayavi.modules.surface import Surface
from mayavi.tools.pipeline import scalar_field
from mayavi.core.ui.mayavi_scene import MayaviScene

# Read the NetCDF file using xarray
dataset = xr.open_dataset('time_series.nc', decode_times=False)

# Extract latitude, longitude, and temperature data
latitude = dataset['LAT852_1008'].values
longitude = dataset['LON2982_3207'].values
temperature = dataset['WATER_TEMP'][0, 0, :, :]

# Create a meshgrid of latitude and longitude
lon_grid, lat_grid = np.meshgrid(longitude, latitude)

# Create a PyQt application
app = QApplication([])
window = QMainWindow()
window.setWindowTitle('Mayavi with PyQt')

# Create a QWidget for Mayavi visualization
mayavi_widget = QWidget(window)
mayavi_widget.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

# Configure the window appearance
palette = QPalette()
palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, Qt.black)
window.setPalette(palette)

# Create a QVBoxLayout for the Mayavi widget
layout = QVBoxLayout(mayavi_widget)
layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

# Create a MayaviScene object
scene = MayaviScene(parent=mayavi_widget)
scene.background = (0, 0, 0)

# Define the update function
def update_figure():
    for time in range(len(dataset['WATER_TEMP']['TIME'])):
        temperature_new = dataset['WATER_TEMP'][time, 0, :, :]
        mlab.clf()
        mlab.mesh(lon_grid, lat_grid, temperature_new, colormap='jet')
        mlab.colorbar(title='Temperature')
        surface = scalar_field(lon_grid, lat_grid, temperature_new)
        mlab.pipeline.surface(surface, opacity=0.7)
        mlab.view(azimuth=180, elevation=90)
        mlab.savefig('frame_%04d.png' % (time + 1))
        scene.camera.azimuth(180)
        scene.camera.elevation(90)
        scene.render()
        window.update()
        t.sleep(3)
        mlab.draw()

# Create a QPushButton for the pause button
pause_button = QPushButton('Pause')

# Create a QPushButton for the play button
play_button = QPushButton('Play')

# Create a QHBoxLayout for the buttons
buttons_layout = QHBoxLayout()
buttons_layout.addWidget(pause_button)
buttons_layout.addWidget(play_button)

# Add the buttons layout to the main layout
layout.addLayout(buttons_layout)

# Connect the buttons to the corresponding actions
pause_button.clicked.connect(lambda: mlab.draw(stop=True))
play_button.clicked.connect(update_figure)

# Start the update loop
update_figure()

# Set the MayaviScene as the central widget of the QMainWindow
window.setCentralWidget(scene)

# Show the QMainWindow
window.show()

# Run the PyQt application
app.exec_()
```

Comment: You didn't post the full error traceback, but I suppose that it happens in the `setCentralWidget()` line. You probably need to change the argument to `mayavi_widget`, instead of `scene`. Note that using blocking functions as `time.sleep()` is discouraged in UI environments, as they completely block the event loop (thus preventing proper rendering and event handling); you probably need to revise that whole function in order to call it every time a new render has to happen, then call that function using a QTimer.